# Detect if DLL is loaded via PHP or Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, dll, toolbar, detect

Is there anyway to detect if a DLL is loaded via php (possibly javascript)? Specifically, im trying to check if a DLL of a toolbar is loaded or not in php and perform actions based on the result.

Comment: Are client and server the _same_ machine, i.e. `localhost`?

Answer (score 2):

With PHP? Certainly not unless it adds itself to the User Agent header.

With JavaScript? Well that depends on the fact if the toolbar exposes itself to JavaScript or not.

Answer (score 0):

"Toolbar" sounds like something at the client side, so - no, most likely you will not be able to find out anything about it in the server side. Hence, not through PHP.

JavaScript is also limited to the available API of the DOM. If the toolbar does not extend the DOM somehow, you will not be able to find out that it is there.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, it's a private toolbar, so i dont think it extends the dom.